# Unable to define a PK for a SQL Server table created by importing Excel sheet

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have imported an Excel sheet using the import wizard provided by SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio, to create a new table. Now it automatically created a table. But if I try to add a PK for the table, I get an error that there is a duplicate PK. But in Management Studio there is no sign for the PK :_

[image]

Now I generate a script for this table and I got this result:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OSLookupInfo]
(
    [Version] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Release Date] [float] NULL,
    [Build Number] [float] NULL,
    [Installer Build Number] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

How can I modify this table to have the `Version` column as the PK, instead of the current PK which seems to be the `[Installer Build Number]`...

Comment: we have data inside the table ? if it is then make sure data should not dublicate

Comment: @tinka but not sure what is the PK ? is it all the columns together ?

Comment: PK does not accept any dublicacy https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189039.aspx

Comment: yes i knwo but is there any PK for my table ?

Comment: right click on `Version` column arrow and select `set primary key` option and save tabel but make sure data should not dublicate other wise it will give an error. remove dublicate data then do same thing and save

Comment: Right now, judging from your screen shot, there is **no** primary key defined. No PK *can* be defined, since all columns appear to allow NULLs